# How to drop elements in dataset that can cause an error while training a TensorFlow Lite model

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a simple image classification model using TensorFlow Lite. I am following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification) documentation to write my code. As specified in the documentation, in order to train my model, I have written `model = image_classifier.create(train_data, model_spec=model_spec.get('mobilenet_v2'), validation_data=validation_data)`. After training for a few seconds, however, I get an `InvalidArgumentError`. I believe that the error is due to something in my dataset but it is too difficult to eliminate all the sources of the error from the dataset manually because it consists of thousands of images. After some research, I found a potential solution - I could use `tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors` which would "produce a dataset that contains the same elements as the input, but silently drop any elements that caused an error." From the documentation, however, ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/ignore_errors)) I couldn't figure out how to integrate this transformation function with my code. If I place the line `dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())` before training the model, the system doesn't know which elements to drop. If I place the line after, the system never reaches the line because an error arises in training. Moreover, the system gives an error message `AttributeError: 'ImageClassifierDataLoader' object has no attribute 'apply'`. I would appreciate if someone can tell me how to integrate `tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors()` with my model or possible alternatives to the issue I am facing.

Comment: Could you provide more details of `InvalidArgumentError`? It might actually be just one kind of error you should fix.

" ...before training the model, the system doesn't know which elements to drop." What does it mean exactly? Do you still get the same error?

Comment: @Proko The `InvalidArgumentError` states "Got 19 frames, but animated gifs can only be decoded by tf.io.decode_gif or tf.io.decode_image"

Comment: @Proko by the line "...before training the model, the system doesn't know which elements to drop", I mean that the system hasn't reached the line `model = image_classifier.create(train_data, model_spec=model_spec.get('mobilenet_v2'), validation_data=validation_data)` yet so it doesn't know what elements are causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are exactly following the documentation then
**`tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors`** won't work for you because you are not loading your data using tf.data,You are most probably using **`from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader`**.

**Note:** Please mention the complete code snippet to help you out to solve the issue

Comment: Yes, I am exactly following the documentation so as you have mentioned, I have used `from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader` (The reason I am using TensorFlow Lite is because I need to upload the model into Android Studio). Can you specify what all should be mentioned in the complete code snippet because I am working on a google colab notebook and I thought only the training part was of relevance.

Comment: you can paste the google colab link in your question and also please try uninstalling tensorflow and installing tensorflow==2.5.0

Comment: I do not want to share the link because I am working on a school project and have been specifically prohibited from sharing my algorithm with others. However, you can assume that my code is exactly the same as the one in the documentation with the exception of the dataset.

Comment: If I `!pip3 install tensorflow==2.5.0`, I get the following error: `UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.` when I try to train my model.

Comment: what is the image format that you are using ?  and if you can't share the link , then I would suggest you to paste the code snipper>

Comment: I have a dataset consisting of .png and .jpg images. Would converting everything to .png help?

Comment: I am not sure, because I can't know which part of the code is causing the error unless we can see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238743/discussion-between-keertika-jain-and-anonymous-person).

Comment: hi, were you able to solve it.?

Comment: Converting all images to .png worked!